# How to get proper shape and color for points in legend when adding geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I add `geom_smooth`, then I'm getting rectangles of different color in the *shape* legend instead of black circles. How can I prevent this? Here is the [sample code](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=dujLnHHy&version=2).

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), z=runif(100))
qplot(x, y, size=z, data=df) +
  geom_smooth(method='loess', aes(weight=z))
```

[image: Incorrect point shape and color in legend]

Comment: The `weight` doesn't matter, just as problematic with a `geom_smooth` with no weight specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed by specifying that the `size` aesthetic is specific to the point layer:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point(aes(size = z)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "loess", aes(weight = z))
```